# do the math for each data in database sql post result to database in php

Tags: php

I'd like to fetch data from my 2 sql database and do some math and post the result in database
let's say my table1 is like this

```
+---+---+----------------------------+
| A | B |             C              |
+---+---+----------------------------+
| 2 | 9 | result from A*B*D*E in php |
| 1 | 8 | result from A*B*D*E in php |
| 4 | 7 | result from A*B*D*E in php |
| 3 | 6 | result from A*B*D*E in php |
| 6 | 5 | result from A*B*D*E in php |
| 6 | 5 | result from A*B*D*E in php |
| 5 | 4 | result from A*B*D*E in php |
+---+---+----------------------------+
```

and my table2 is like this

```
+---+----+
| D | E  |
+---+----+
| 1 | 9  |
| 2 | 7  |
| 3 | 8  |
| 4 | 6  |
| 5 | 5  |
| 6 | 3  |
| 7 | 2  |
+---+----+
```

so far what i've done

```
  // database connection
  include_once("config.php");

  // Query
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table1");
  $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table2");


  //Source1      
  while($user_data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
  {
     $A[] = $user_data1['A'];
     $B[] = $user_data1['B'];
  }
    
  //Source2
  while($user_data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) 
  {
    $D[] = $user_data2['D'];
    $E[] = $user_data2['E'];
  }
  foreach (array_combine($A, $B) as $ValueA=> $ValueB)
  {
    foreach (array_combine($D, $E) as $ValueD=> $ValueE)
    {
      $result1 = $ValueA*$ValueB*ValueD*ValueE;
      $val = 0.123;
      $result2[] = $result1*$val;
    }    
    $final result = min($result2);
    echo round($final result, 2);
    unset($result2);
  }
```

I haven't inserted the database yet
still echoing for debug if the math is correct
somehow this code found some bug
for example using my database the final result only echo/showing 6 math result
because in table1 row 5 and 6 has same data
btw of course in my table1 and 2 has primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change C in this case, you don't even need PHP. To UPDATE a value in MySQL with multiple tables just add them with a `,` when selecting the tables, like this:

```sql
UPDATE table1,table2 SET C = table1.A * table1.B * table2.D * table2.E WHERE C IS NULL;
```

Executing this code once will update all rows so that `C = A*B*D*E` as wanted where C is not yet set or NULL. If you want to update all rows you can just remove the `WHERE` condition

Note: Sometimes (at least for me) SQL will give a warning when having no WHERE condition in the SQL query. To bypass this just add `WHERE 1=1` at the end.

Comment: Then you can just run the code with [`query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) each time you add a row to the tables

Comment: my table 1 got value for A and B from apps
my table 2 is fix value
i need to run my php every 5 seconds
since every 5 seconds my table 1 has around 50 new data

Comment: Why can't you just set C when you insert the row into table 1? The other option of running over everything every 5 seconds is possible with cronjobs. [Here's a tutorial for that](https://dsharpdotnet.wordpress.com/2013/07/04/how-to-use-cronjob-to-execute-periodical-mysql-queries/)

Comment: okay i guess i need to move to sql instead of using php thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Just for my understanding: you want to calculate a value for your calculation you need some data from table 1 that is clear, but also from table2 But which one? I guess you want to use the data from the same row ( so row 1 from table1 and row 1 from table2, row 2 from table 1 and row 2 from table2 ) right? Now you have an problem because when you make a `select * from table` You do not know in which order they give back from your database. Most time it may be the same order as you have input them, but there is no garantie. You have sayed you have an primary key on each table, how have you defined them?  I guess you may have a id column, so you can join your table on that id?

Comment: yes i think i need to move to sql as it is more simple than use php